# Auto-bots and Car Culture

Tags: transformers

One of the things that perplexes me is that the autobots didn't really adopt car culture very much, or maybe I am missing some things. For example, did an Autobot ever have personalized mudflaps?  Dice on the mirror or raccoon tail on the antenna? Truck nuts?

Comment: Consider dropping the last graphic part of your question if you care about votes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the vehicles the Transformers turned into were highly customized. The most obvious example was Optimus Prime himself turning into a Western Star 5700.

Here is how the truck comes "stock":

[image: Stock 5700]

And here is how Optimus customized it:

[image: Optimus Prime]

As you can see smoke stacks, front bumper, clearance lights, mirrors, and fuel tanks are all very customized - not just painted.

I'm fairly confident custom mud flaps would not have been a problem, and I can't say for sure is he didn't actually have them.

Of course the most famous of our Transformers, Bumblebee, was certainly not a generic 2016 Camaro (pictured below):

[image: 2016 Camaro]

Bumblebee from *Transformers 5: The Last Knight* enjoyed really spicing up his image with completely customized ground effects, a spoiler, and hood scoops.

[image: Bumblebee]

Answer (score 2):

Hot Rod(Rodimus) exemplifies a lot of car culture both in physical design and the character's personality.

Despite being a futuristic car, Hot Rod features a custom flames paint job, a massive spoiler, an exposed engine, and elaborate chromed exhaust pipes.
[image: Hot Rod]

As for personality, the specs on the back of his original toy box describe him as an all-American-boy, typical adolescent, who doesn't follow rules too closely. He's impulsive and can be hotheaded. A toy commercial featured him taunting his enemies and saying, "watch my smoke!" He is often described as a rash and arrogant, turbo-revving young punk.

Beyond Hot Rod, there are numerous other Transformers with modifications and embellishments beyond a stock vehicle. From the original cartoon, Wheeljack and Jazz are both modified for racing and feature racing paint jobs as well. Sunstreaker is a customized Lamborghini Countach with supercharger intakes. The Hot Rod Patrol was a collection of four Micromasters who turned into cars with superchargers and custom flame paint jobs. Side Burn from *Robots in Disguise* also featured a custom flames paint job and an exposed engine.

Regarding mudflaps in particular, according to [TF Wiki](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Elita_One_(G1)):

> In the The War Within #4, Elita One's silhouette is depicted on Optimus Prime's mudflap in vehicle mode, similar to the "Trucker Lady" silhouette decal seen on modern vehicles. Optimus Prime also has a bobble-head of her inside his cab.

[image: Mudflaps]

Comment: When quoting from something you should indicate as such what is a quote and what isn’t. It’s best to do this with quote markdown, >, as I’ve done here for you.